Automatically Move Row down Based On Dropdown
I am new to Google Sheets, Can someone help me with the code to move the entire row to an other certain row if I change the Column F to 'done'.
Ex : if i change F3 to 'done' then entire row 3 will be automatically moved to after row 40
Note : Filter function did not work in this case for us ^^
i tried macro but... had to active macro manually ^^ , it would be great if a script that help to do it automatically, thanks for any help


Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Automatically Move Row Based on Dropdown Using Installable onChange Trigger
Try using Google Apps Script to achieve your expected output.
The function below moves rows marked as Done in column F to start after row 40. It clears their original position and pastes them in their new position, starting at row 40, without disrupting the sheet layout.
After that, set up the installable onChange trigger so that it automatically updates whenever a change occurs.
You can try this Code:
function moveToRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 39, 6);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var arrayToPaste = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 38; i++) {
    if (data[i][5] == "Done") {
      arrayToPaste.push(data[i]);
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 6).clear();
    }
  }

  var rowToPaste = sheet.getLastRow();
  if (rowToPaste <= 39) {
    rowToPaste = 40;
  }

  sheet.getRange(rowToPaste + 1, 1, arrayToPaste.length, 6).setValues(arrayToPaste);

}

Setting Up the Installable onChange Trigger:
1.) Open the script editor (Extensions > Apps Script).
2.) In the script editor, go to Triggers (clock icon) in the left sidebar.
3.) Click on + Add Trigger in the bottom-right corner.
4.) Select moveToRow as the function to run.
5.) Choose From spreadsheet and select On change as the event type.
6.) Save the trigger.
Sample Output:


Reference:
Installable Trigger

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. Sample outputs are usually unnecessary.
